# Pandas date_range with specific time ranges

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I am trying to use `pd.date_range()` to create a `DatetimeIndex` that spans over multiple days with a frequency in seconds. However, the time range for each day should be restricted between 05:00:00 and 22:00:00

Something along the lines of (doesn't work of course):

```
times_c = pd.date_range(start="2015-01-01",end="2015-01-10",freq="S")
mask_c = ((times_c.time < dt.datetime.strptime("22:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")) | (times_c.time > dt.datetime.strptime("05:00:00","%H:%M:%S")))
times_c = times_c[mask_c]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`indexer_between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html):

```
times_c[times_c.indexer_between_time('05:00:00', '22:00:00')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
times_c = pd.date_range(start="2015-01-01", end="2015-01-10", freq="S")
times_c[(times_c.hour<22) | (times_c.hour>5)]
```

Comment: Still includes all times because 23 is larger than 5

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this.

```
times_c[((times_c.hour >= 5) & (times_c.hour < 22)) | ((times_c.hour == 22) &(times_c.minute == 0) & (times_c.second == 0))]
```

Let's get all time times greater than hour 5 and less than 22, then get that edge case of 22 with zero minutes and zero seconds.